# How to use alias in a left join?

Tags: mysql, left-join, alias

I have a problem in my MySQL command

```
select upper(file_type) as 'ItemType', ponum as 'Policy Number', office as 'Office', fullname as 'FullName', remarks as 'Remarks', concat(x.id, '-',x.file_type) as 'Identification'
from (select * from active_tb
union
select * from processed_tb) as x
left join filelocation as y on x.identification = y.f_id
```

I get `unknown column x.Identification` when trying to execute the query.

First I join two different tables, then select the columns I need, then assign an alias. I need to concatenate the identification column.

But I cannot use the alias in a left join.

Answer (score 2):

Just build your identification column in your left join sub query first.

```
SELECT upper(file_type) AS 'ItemType',
       ponum            AS 'Policy Number',
       office           AS 'Office',
       fullname         AS 'FullName',
       remarks          AS 'Remarks',
       x.identification
FROM   (SELECT *,
               concat(x.id, '-', x.file_type) AS 'identification'
        FROM   active_tb
        UNION
        SELECT *,
               concat(x.id, '-', x.file_type) AS 'identification'
        FROM   processed_tb) AS x
       LEFT JOIN filelocation AS y
              ON x.identification = y.f_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now. 
Here is my code:

```
select ItemType, 'Policy Number', Office, fullname, identification, f_location
from (select upper(file_type) as 'ItemType', ponum as 'Policy Number', office as 'Office', fullname as 'FullName', remarks as 'Remarks', concat(id, '-',file_type) as 'Identification' from active_tb
union
select upper(file_type) as 'ItemType', ponum as 'Policy Number', office as 'Office', fullname as 'FullName', remarks as 'Remarks', concat(id, '-',file_type) as 'Identification' from processed_tb) as x
left join filelocation on filelocation.f_id = x.Identification
```

Please comment other suggestions.

Comment: Yup, that is what i suggested in my answer. You beat me to the punch!