# Using MySQL Keywork Within Same SELECT

Tags: mysql

I am working with some MySQL queries. I am hoping there might be a way to use a statement's AS name within the same statement. I don't know how else to describe it other than showing you an example.

```
SELECT facebook.Spend,
    validclick.Revenue,
    yahoo.Spend,
    (yahoo.Spend + facebook.spend) AS TSpend,
    (validclick.Revenue - TSpend) AS Profit
FROM validclick
JOIN yahoo ON yahoo.Campaign = validclick.Campaign
JOIN facebook ON facebook.Campaign = validclick.Campaign
```

I would like to be able to use TSpend as the name within other statements. I am using some case statments and long equations and being able to use these easier names would make things a lot easier. When I try MySQL says there's an error but you guys know everything so if there's a way to do it you would know!

Here is the actual query:

```
            SELECT validclick.Website AS Website, 
                (yahoo.Spend + facebook.Spend) AS TSpend, 
                (validclick.Revenue - TSpend) AS Profit, 
                (TSpend / Profit) AS ROI, 
            FROM 
                (SELECT camp.CampaignName AS CampaignName, 
                    MAX(camp.Website) AS Website, 
                    SUM(vc.Revenue) AS Revenue 
                FROM 
                    (SELECT AffID, 
                        MAX(CampaignName) AS CampaignName, 
                        Website
                    FROM campaigns 
                    $campaignmanagersql .
                    GROUP BY AffID) AS camp 
                JOIN 
                    (SELECT AffID, 
                        SUM(Clicks) AS Clicks, 
                        SUM(AffiliateRevenue) AS Revenue, 
                    FROM validclickvc 
                    WHERE Date BETWEEN '2018-01-07' AND '2018-01-08' 
                    GROUP BY AffID) AS vc 
                ON vc.AffID = camp.AffID 
                GROUP BY camp.CampaignName) AS validclick 
            LEFT JOIN 
                (SELECT CampaignName, 
                    SUM(Spend) AS Spend,
                    SUM(OutboundClicks) AS PaidClicks 
                FROM facebookads 
                WHERE Date BETWEEN '2018-01-07' AND '2018-01-08' 
                GROUP BY CampaignName) AS facebook 
            ON validclick.CampaignName = facebook.CampaignName 
            LEFT JOIN 
                (SELECT CampaignName, 
                    SUM(Spend) AS Spend,
                    SUM(Clicks) AS PaidClicks 
                FROM yahoogemini 
                WHERE Date BETWEEN '2018-01-07' AND '2018-01-08' 
                GROUP BY CampaignName) AS yahoo 
            ON validclick.CampaignName = yahoo.CampaignName 
            ORDER BY CampaignName
```

Comment: Don't use the alias Spend because it will be ambigous. You already have 2 field with the same name. (facebook.Spend, yahoo.Spend)

Comment: Even if I use a different name it doesn't work

Comment: Can you include your actual query ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid yes! Give me a sec it's quite a beast. I'm going to cut it down a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can use `AS Column` only in `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses.

You can wrap your query into another `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT facebook.Spend,
        validclick.Revenue,
        yahoo.Spend,
        (yahoo.Spend + facebook.spend) AS TSpend,
        (validclick.Revenue - TSpend) AS Profit
    FROM validclick
    JOIN yahoo ON yahoo.Campaign = validclick.Campaign
    JOIN facebook ON facebook.Campaign = validclick.Campaign
    ) AS t1
WHERE TSpend > 10
```

However this will have performance impact, because no indexes will be involved in search by those computed columns

Answer (score 1):

For using aliases with LEFT JOIN you should refer to this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42848658/4505007